# Is there any way to check the most requested(in terms of IO) areas of the file-system inside a docker container?

Tags: filesystems, docker, io, aufs

I've recently read this interesting suggestion under "Performance best practices" subtitle here: https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/aufs-driver/

> **Use volumes for write-heavy workloads**: Volumes provide the best and most predictable performance for write-heavy workloads. This is
>   because they bypass the storage driver and do not incur any of the
>   potential overheads introduced by thin provisioning and copy-on-write.
>   Volumes have other benefits, such as allowing you to share data among
>   containers and persisting even when no running container is using
>   them.

..and Ok, when provisioning each one of our containers, we always think about major needs, based on the reason of existence of this container, and determine which directories should be a volume because there's going to happen tons of read/write.

**My question is**: how to inspect a container file-system to determine if some directory inside it should be a volume and '*bypass the storage driver*' but it still not bypassing?

Let me explain a little more: Lets say I check out /var/log inside a container to see what is happening there.. and I realize there is a process log-files with lots of writing per minute so I decide to transform it as a volume.

But, what if there is another dir like /var/www or /var/spool, or something else? Is there any way to check the most requested areas of the file-system inside a container, in terms of IO?